# Cannot install docker on RBPi 3 (strecht) through convenience script

Tags: raspbian-stretch, docker

I am trying to install `docker` on my Raspberry Pi 3

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Following [Docker's own guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-convenience-script), I use the convenience script as follows

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

But the installation does not complete. Instead, I get this error:

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: 26ff363bcf3b3f5a00498ac43694bf1c7d9ce16c
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
W: GPG error: http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
W: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/httpredir.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 151.101.114.133 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea how I could solve this?

EDIT 1:  I am not sure the problem lays in the install script, becuase if I run `sudo apt-get update` I get a similar error (I added the "[--->]" for clarity)

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY CBF8D6FD518E17E1
[--->] W: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.packager.io/srv/deb/opf/openproject/stable/10/debian 9 InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
[--->] E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/httpredir.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_i18n_Translation-en.bz2 - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 151.101.114.133 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please add the output of these commands to the question: `cat /etc/os-release`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the script but `apt update`

I solved it by 1) installing `debian-archive-keyring`[*]

```
sudo apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```

And 2) removing the contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial`

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo rm *

## this will only remove files in the folder, but will not touch the partial folder, which needs to be accessed as root

su
root@****:/var/lib/apt# cd partial
root@****:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial# rm *
exit

# after that I just ran
sudo apt update
```

[*]I am not sure this step is necessary but since I did it I wanted to include it for clarity

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Raspbian Stretch** but the installation script uses the repository of **Raspbian Jessie**. This cannot work.

You have to use an installation script for Stretch or modify yours to use the repository of Stretch. I don't know if this can be done easily.

By the way, Raspbian Jessie is deprecated since years and out of any support since 2020-01-01. Its repository has been moved to the archive repositories.

Comment: I've been looking at the script and, as far as I can understand it, it tries to extract the current machine running the script itself. But I am no expert perhaps I am wrong. I also edited the question to add that the same error displays also when trying to update the package list.